# How to split a Dataframe column whose data is not unique

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a column called users in dataframe which doesn't have a unique format. I am doing a data cleanup project as the data looks unreadable.

```
   company                Users
    A   [{"Name":"Martin","Email":"name_1@email.com","EmpType":"Full"},{"Name":"Rick","Email":"name_2@email.com","Dept":"HR"}]
    B   [{"Name":"John","Email":"name_2@email.com","EmpType":"Full","Dept":"Sales" }]
```

I used the below query to this has broke down the data frame as below

```
df2 = df 
df2 = df2.join(df['Users_config'].str.split('},{', expand=True).add_prefix('Users'))

company                   Users0                                                     Users1
    A   "Name":"Martin","Email":"name_1@email.com","EmpType":"Full"              "Name":"Rick","Email":"name_2@email.com","Dept":"HR"
    B   "Name":"John","Email":"name_2@email.com","EmpType":"Full","Dept":"Sales"
```

and further breaking the above df with "," using the same query I got the output as

```
  Company      Users01               Users02        Users03                Users10             Users11            Users12                             
  1     "Name":"Martin" "Email":"name_1@email.com"  "EmpType":"Full" "Name":"Rick"  "Email":"name_2@email.com"  "Dept":"HR" 
  2     "Name":"John"   "Email":"name_2@email.com"  "EmpType":"Full"  "Dept":"Sales"
```

As this dataframe looks messy I want to get the output as below. I feel the best way to name the column is to use the column value "Name" from "Name":"Martin" itself and If we hardcore using df.rename the column name will get mismatch.

```
Company  Name_1        Email_1    EmpType_1 Dept_1  Name_2  Email_2         Dept_2                             
  1     Martin    name_1@email.com   Full           Rick   name_2@email.com  "HR" 
  2     John     name_2@email.com"   Full   Sales
```

Is there any way I can get the above output from the original dataframe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Use:**

```
df['Users'] = df['Users'].apply(ast.literal_eval)

d = df.explode('Users').reset_index(drop=True)
d = d.join(pd.DataFrame(d.pop('Users').tolist()))
d = d.set_index(['company', d.groupby('company').cumcount().add(1).astype(str)]).unstack()
d.columns = d.columns.map('_'.join)
```

**Details:**

First we use [`ast.literal_eval`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html) to evaluate the strings in `Users` column,  then use [`DataFrame.explode`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html) on column `Users` to create a dataframe `d`.

```
print(d)
  company                                                                              Users
0       A                 {'Name': 'Martin', 'Email': 'name_1@email.com', 'EmpType': 'Full'}
1       A                        {'Name': 'Rick', 'Email': 'name_2@email.com', 'Dept': 'HR'}
2       B  {'Name': 'John', 'Email': 'name_2@email.com', 'EmpType': 'Full', 'Dept': 'Sales'}
```

Create a new dataframe from the `Users` column in `d` and use [`DataFrame.join`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html) to join this new dataframe with `d`.

```
print(d)
  company    Name             Email EmpType   Dept
0       A  Martin  name_1@email.com    Full    NaN
1       A    Rick  name_2@email.com     NaN     HR
2       B    John  name_2@email.com    Full  Sales
```

Use [`DataFrame.groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) on column `company` then use [`groupby.cumcount`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html) to create a counter for each group, then use [`DataFrame.set_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) to set the index of `d` as `company`  + `counter`. Then use [`DataFrame.unstack`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.unstack.html) to reshape the dataframe creating `MultiIndex` columns.

```
print(d)
           Name                   Email                   EmpType        Dept     
              1     2                 1                 2       1    2      1    2
company                                                                           
A        Martin  Rick  name_1@email.com  name_2@email.com    Full  NaN    NaN   HR
B          John   NaN  name_2@email.com               NaN    Full  NaN  Sales  NaN
```

Finally use `map` along with `.join` to flatten the `MultiIndex` columns.

```
print(d)
         Name_1 Name_2           Email_1           Email_2 EmpType_1 EmpType_2 Dept_1 Dept_2
company                                                                                     
A        Martin   Rick  name_1@email.com  name_2@email.com      Full       NaN    NaN     HR
B          John    NaN  name_2@email.com               NaN      Full       NaN  Sales    NaN
```

Comment: Thank you @Shubham Sharma.  Your answer worked when I have a row limit of 80. However I am getting "ValueError: malformed node or string: <_ast.Name object at 0x1228d92b0>" if row count more than 90. Not sure if the issue is with data itself..

Comment: Hi.. I appreciate your help.. I finally found out that the issue was with data. I fixed it by removing it.

Comment: @JackJack Great! Happy coding.